# Ubuntu restarting or freezing on closing lid && heating issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, power-management, overheating

I am working on `Ubuntu 20.04` on `ASUS ZenBook UX534FTC with 4GB GeForce GTX 1650 Max-Q GPU` and have been using Ubuntu for more than a year now. Everything was working fine up until a week before but now I don't know what have I installed or which settings I have changed unknowingly which has now resulted in very weird behavior - upon closing and reopening the lid of my laptop, either of the two events happen: a reboot of entire OS which results in me having to enter my user password and then again open all the tabs, apps, etc, or, the screen just goes blank with a blinking cursor on the top left corner, upon which I have to press the power button and restart forcefully. I practically can't close my lid now.

Also, I am having very serious heating issues as well. I had this heating issue earlier as well, but I was able to control it by installing `tlp`, changing GPU driver from `X.org` to `nvidia` and maybe doing a few more things. but since the past 4-5 days, it is becoming unbearable now. I can barely keep my hands on top of my laptop and type - It has become so hot that I can't touch the back of my laptop now even when there is nothing running other than just a few browser tabs (already ordered a multi-fan cooling pad but it doesn't solve the inherent problem).

I have `dual-booted` my laptop with `Windows 11` and `Ubuntu 20.04` and there seem to be no such issues with Windows - neither with the lid nor with heating. This clearly indicates it is entirely Ubuntu's problem.

It is also very likely that `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (which took 15-20 minutes to complete) might have resulted in this mess because I ran this command 4-5 days ago which is approximately the same time when I started observing all this.

I believe there could be some issue with the GPU driver as well - maybe after running the above command, the GPU driver again switched back from nvidia to X.org and I switched it back from the `X.org open-source driver` to the `NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-450-server (proprietary)`. This gave some relief with respect to heating but was still not significant.

I wish I could do a clean install of Ubuntu, but I don't have the time to do so immediately, and hence, in dire need of some quick solution. I have seen some of the posts by other users, such as editing some properties in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` but of no help. Kindly mention any other details that are required to solve these issues (such as some config files?).